# How to load XML for custom parsing on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my Android application I'm using the DocumentBuilder API instead of XmlPullParser. Now the problem is that using `getApplicationContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.myfile)` I get an instance of XmlResourceParser whereas I need a File or InputStream or something like that which I can read directly or pass to the DocumentBuilder. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `openRawResource()` instead of `getXml()`.

Comment: Haha, just wanted to answer my own question while you posted yours :-D

Comment: I actually checked an older question of mine where I already had this figured out :P